# What happened to Active Databases?

Tags: programming-languages, history, database-theory

When reading the literature on declarative programming technology. A particular technology that sounded promising is active databases. It essentially allows the programmer to specify rules about data that generate more data. On face value it seems like a great thing to have when compared to your neighborhood average imperative code.

There are many production rules systems out there, but they are not integrated with a database system. As I understand it, active databases would have been the logical evolution for  production systems.

But, the subject seems to have died off. It is hard to find articles on Active Databases. And I can't really find a product that implements anything like that. My question is, what happened?

Comment: No, it wouldn't have been 'the logical evolution'.  There are many alternative approaches. Besides, the buzzwords keep changing all the time: your Active Database is another person's Deductive Database or RDF Store or Ontology or Rules Engine or whatever.

Comment: Actually I did find a reference, that triggers were an attempt to incorporate ideas from Active Databases.